# Bs4 Как парсить информацию из alt внутри тега?

Tags: python, парсер, beautiful-soup, bs4

Мне нужен парс текста внутри alt (hello world) при помощи bs4
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал делать это при помощи find_all, но он ищет текст во всей ветке.

Comment: Пожалуйста, не выставляйте исходный код в виде картинок. Луше перекопируйте его в вопрос.

Comment: не думал, что код html стоит писать в виде текста. я просто привёл его, как пример

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import get


html = get(r'ССЫЛКА_НА_САЙТ').text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

attributes_dictionary = soup.find('img').attrs['alt'] 
#attrs возвращает атрибуты тега в виде словаря
```

Comment: это работает, но мне нужен парс с сайта, а не вывод текста, который я сам писал

Comment: Тогда используйте модуль `requests` как показано в моем обновленном ответе.

Comment: выходит ошибка 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'attrs'

Comment: Я не могу знать какой сайт вы именно парсите. По этому не как не могу вам помочь. Для каждого сайта свой подход. Если вы хотите чтобы я вам как-то помог - киньте ссылку на сайт который вы парсите.

Comment: https://www.origin.com/rus/ru-ru/game-library

Comment: Простите, но я перешел по вашей ссылке под своим аккаунтом и проверил код страницы, но не обнаружил там не одного тега `<img>`. Похоже его также не смог найти и `bs4` и по этому вернул  `None`.